# Can I use Different charger: Similar Voltage, lower Amps?

Tags: speakers, charger

i have an old style philips bluetooth speaker ipad ipod doc but lost the charger. It is a ds7700/98 and the specs say input is 100 to 240 v and 1.5 a and 50/60 htz as well as output 10 v and 3.5 a.  I have lots of chargers laying around or can i find something on say ebay

Answer (score 0):

You can replace charger with similar, depending of device charger will be ok or not, but remember this and you find right charger;
Voltage is provided (or pushed) by the charger (10V), it doesn't matter if your device need more or less power.
Amperage is taken (or pulled) by the device being powered. 
The answer is yes, you can use similar charger, with 10V (+/- 0,5V will be ok, except newest iPhone and similar devices) but amperage must be higher if you want to have full charging. 
If amperage is a bit lower, let say about 10%, it will charge the battery but if you want to listening music during charging with lower amperage you do not have enough power for high volume, simple as that. 
Hope this will help you !